# Need help on this geometry problem about angles

Tags: geometry

A certain trapezoid has these properties: Its diagonals are congruent and perpendicular to each other, and its longer base lengths is equal to the length of a diagonal. What is the sum of the degree measures of the two acute angles of this trapezoid?

I looked all the properties and am not able to get there. Any hint is greatly appreciated. I want to solve this with any hints.

Answer (score 3):

Because AC = AB, then triangle ABC is isosceles. Hence $45 + x = y$ where y = 180 - 90 - x.

Solve $45 + x = 180 - 90 - x$ for $x$ to determine the two equal base angles.

[image]

Comment: This makes perfect sense. Thanks a lot. I totally forgot about Isosceles.. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

Let $ABCD$ be our trapezoid with $AD||BC$, $AD>BC$, $AB=CD$, $AC=AD$ and $AC\perp BD$.

Thus, since $\measuredangle CAD=45^{\circ},$ we obtain:
$$\measuredangle BAD+\measuredangle CAD=\measuredangle ACD+\measuredangle CAD=180^{\circ}-45^{\circ}=135^{\circ}.$$

Comment: Didnt get how AB=CD here? Also from the above deduction, does it mean angle BAD and angle ACD are equal? and also, dont understand how its 180-45

Comment: @Sreeram Ravinoothala $AB=CD$ by the given. See please better my solution.